# Alcohol good or bad?

Tags: psychology, physiology, alcohol

I see moderate alcohol shows (supposed) benefits for health and long life. I am 42 and experienced a mid life crisis 4 months ago (initially a nervous breakdown). I am slowly getting better but stil have anxiety bouts. My life is now moving forward including skiing with my son, going out to restaurants, traveling, etc.; all of which I was not able to do the first month after my breakdown. I am doing ALL the right things now but just have small anxiety bouts of spinning thoughts of "when will I get 100% healed":

My life now includes:
Eating very healthy.
Running on a regular basis.
Instead of working on my business 12-15 hours a day/7 days a week, I am working 5 days a week, maybe 6-8 hours a day.
Taking all kinds of vitamins/herbs etc.
Working with some small Cognitive Behavioral Therapies.
Meditation.
I am going to be seeing a hypnotherapist.

So . . . . I have always enjoyed a regular glass or two of port wine each night for many years. Will this prevent me from getting healed from my nervous breakdown symptoms?

Comment: More dupes: http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/2735/does-alcohol-cause-cancer http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/9797/is-a-glass-of-red-wine-a-day-beneficial-for-the-heart http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/13643/does-the-combination-of-red-wine-and-cheese-cause-bad-dreams http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1059/is-alcohol-beneficial-in-small-amounts http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/13602/does-drinking-alcohol-help-a-sore-throat http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/8197/recommended-alcohol-drinking-quantity-are-they-just-making-it-up

Comment: Claims that alcohol is good for you are not actually about the substance ethanol, but about specific beverages which contain ethanol, along with a mixture of numerous other substances.